# set cursor in login form field on page load

Tags: javascript, forms, text-cursor

I'm trying to get my cursor to load in my login form field on page load.  So i'm using this code that supposedly works in every browser but i can't get it to work in any browser lol.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
document.login.input.focus();
});
</script>
```

Here's the page I'm trying to add it to:
http://test.clickacart.com

This should load the cursor in the first username/email field on page load so user doesn't have to click inside to fill it out.

Comment: That's jQuery, however I don't see you including jQuery in your page.

Comment: Yep, you don't reference jQuery... Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() { $('[name="email_address"]').focus(); });
```

Comment: what jquery?  aren't there a lot of versions?

Comment: ok, i added this and it works now.  <script language="javascript" src="includes/javascript/jquery.1.2.4.js"></script>  Is this a good version?  I don't really know what the difference is btw versions of jquery though.

Comment: you can use google's CDN to reference the latest `1.7.x` version - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js

Comment: so using latest is always recommended?

Answer (score 6):

Most browsers support the autofocus attribute like this...

```
<input type='...' autofocus />
```

The other option is to take the jQuery route like this...

```
$(function () {
   $('[autofocus]').focus()
});
```

Comment: I did notice that this autofocus method seems to not work in IE.  any ideas of a work around in a way that I would understand?  if we have to use jquery or javascript, could you provide the code that works in my scenerio?

Comment: <input type='...' autofocus /> worked! The ready(function .focus methods listed above didn't. Nice, easy code.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the field name by the id within the selector

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fieldId").focus();
});`

Comment: like this? i added an id called user to the email_address input text field.   

      `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).ready(function() { $("#user").focus(); });
     });
      </script>`

Comment: If the id of your field is user, try this. $(document).ready(function() { $("#user").focus(); });

Comment: ok, i tried this and my result code was placed before the <head> tag and it was this and did not work:  
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { $("#user").focus(); });
      </script>`